# Realm+JSON: EXC BAD ACCESS when calling createOrUpdateInRealm:withJSONArray: second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, realm

```
+ (NSDictionary *)mc_inboundMapping {
static NSMutableDictionary *mappingForClassName = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    mappingForClassName = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
});
@synchronized(mappingForClassName) {
    NSDictionary *mapping = mappingForClassName[[self className]];//<----EXC BAD ACCESS here
    if (!mapping) {
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"JSONInboundMappingDictionary");
        if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            mapping = MCValueFromInvocation(self, selector);
        }
        else {
            mapping = [self mc_defaultInboundMapping];
        }
        mappingForClassName[[self className]] = mapping;
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

I'm using `Realm+JSON` with Realm. And got a problem with `Realm+JSON`.
When I attempt to call `createOrUpdateInRealm:withJSONArray:` multiple time in loop for multiple `RLMObjects`, the first `RLMObject` works OK, but the second `RLMObject`(no matter what class is) fails with `EXC BAD ACCESS code1`on static variable.

I think autorelease pool deallocate pointing `NSMutableDictionary`.Anybody got this issue? I'm using `XCode 6.3.2` and `Realm 0.96.3`.

```
+ (NSArray *)createOrUpdateInRealm:(RLMRealm *)realm withJSONArray:(NSArray *)array {
NSInteger count = array.count;
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger index=0; index*kCreateBatchSize<count; index++) {
    NSInteger size = MIN(kCreateBatchSize, count-index*kCreateBatchSize);
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        for (NSInteger subIndex=0; subIndex<size; subIndex++) {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = array[index*kCreateBatchSize+subIndex];
            id object = [self createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withJSONDictionary:dictionary];
            [result addObject:object];
        }
    }
}

return [result copy];
}
```

calling here...

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction];

        if ([collection isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            for (NSString *key in [collection allKeys])
            {
                NSLog(@"Set Data == %@:%@", key, collection[key]);

                id jsData = [collection[key] objectForKey:@"data"];

                if ([key isEqualToString:STATIC_ERROR_MSGS])
                {
                    [SErrorMsgs createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withJSONArray:jsData];
                }
                else if ([key isEqualToString:STATIC_EPISODE])
                {
                    [SEpisode createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withJSONArray:jsData];
                }
                else if ([key isEqualToString:STATIC_INGAME_TUTORIAL])
                {
                    [SIngameTutorial createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withJSONArray:jsData];
                } //more cases.........edited
```

Comment: I though u only need to call `createOrUpdateInRealm:withJSONArray:` 1 time only?

Comment: i meant second time on another RLMObject, so it's always 1 time for each RLMObjects.

Comment: Can you please post your code that is actually calling `createOrUpdateInRealm:withJSONArray` for us to take a look at? Also, is there a reason why you haven't updated to Realm 0.97?

Comment: 0.97 needs XCode 7 so, I can't...well for now. I will post the code. Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the problem(which was mine).
This(R+J) is ARC project and my projects is Non-ARC.
So I had to add -fobjc-arc flag in build phase.